# Подключить parallax.js к проекту

Tags: frontend, npm, parallax, foundation

У меня собранный на основе foundation проект (взят из их директории). 
Мне нужно подключить `parallax.js`, я прописал в терминале

```
npm i --save parallax.js
```

В файле `package.json` зависимость появилась

```
    "dependencies": {
    "foundation-sites": "~6.4.1",
    "jquery": ">=3.0.0",
    "motion-ui": "~1.2.2",
    "parallax.js": "^0.1.0",
    "what-input": "^4.1.3"
  },
```

Но все равно браузер пишет что `parallax({});` это не функция.

Также в папку `assets/js` я кинул файл parallax.js, все равно та же ошибка.

Проект https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B44Y0w-51_ZFRDFUQU1NbVl1dUk

Что я делаю не так?